# How to hide jQueryUI tooltip when mouse moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

I would like to hide a jQueryUI tooltip when mouse is moving over the target, and only show it when it is stationary over the target.

I believe this is the standard behavior for tooltips in windows.

How could this be achievable?

Comment: if it is standard then it is achievable

Comment: answer to your question will be `yes` or `no`. Assuming that is not the answer you want, Please phrase your question

Comment: @TJ there... "how could this be achievable"

Comment: Isn't it the default behavior of `tooltips` even in web ?

Comment: @anmarti nope, the default behavior of tooltips (at least in Chrome) is to show after a certain delay **and** while the user is hovering the element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came out with this solution after reading @nem's post:

```
            var waitTime = 500 // milliseconds to wait with mouse still over target before showing tooltip
            $("*[title]").tooltip({
                open: function(event, ui) {
                    /**
                    * tooltip opens on hover
                    * if mouse is moving we start a timer to show tooltip after waitTime
                    */
                    var tooltipTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {$(this).show();}, waitTime);
                    $(this).on('mousemove.mytooltip', function() {
                        // if mouse moves over target, we 1) hide tooltip, 2) cancel the timer and 3) start a  new timer to show tooltip after waitTime
                        $('.ui-tooltip').hide();
                        window.clearTimeout(tooltipTimer);
                        tooltipTimer = window.setTimeout(function () {$('.ui-tooltip').show();}, waitTime);
                    })
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the default behavior of the jQueryUI tooltip so you have to go around it. After some thought, here's my suggestion. You can play with the thresholds to see what works the best for your use case.

Essentially, my approach is to, once the tooltip opens, bind the `mousemove` event that will control the tooltip visibility. Once the tooltip closes, you unbind that `mousemove` handler. The control will hide the tooltip if the mouse is moving or check if the mouse stopped moving (by measuring the time elapsed after the event,  within a certain threshold) and show the tooltip. Here's the code with appropriate comments:

```js
var isShown = false,              // flag indicating if the tooltip is currently shown
  animationTime = 400,            // show/hide tooltip animation time
  checkIfStoppedThreshold = 1000; // number of milliseconds before we check if the mouse has moved 

$('#target').tooltip({
  open: function(event, ui) {
    // number of moves before we start controlling the tooltip is used 
    // to take into account that the initial call to open will probably
    // also trigger the mousemove event, so we ignore it minMovesCount
    // number of times for the sake of user-friendliness.
    // If minMovesCount moves have happened, we can start controlling 
    // the tooltip and show it every time that the mouse stops moving.
    var minMovesCount = 15;
    $('#target').on('mousemove.mytooltip', function() {
      if (minMovesCount > 0) {
        minMovesCount--;
      } else if (!isShown) { 
        controlTooltip();
      }
    })
  },
  close: function(event, ui) {
    // unbind the mousemove handler since the tooltip is closed
    $('#target').off('mousemove.mytooltip');
  }
});

// called on each mousemove, after minMovesCount mousemoves have happened
function controlTooltip() {
  var tooltip = $('.ui-tooltip'),
    moveTime = Date.now(); // time of the mousemove event

  // hide the tooltip if its not already hidden
  tooltip.fadeOut(animationTime);

  // start the "timer until tooltip is shown"
  setTimeout(function() {

    var allowedPrecisionError = 20; // allowed error in the timing precision for checking mousemove time (in milliseconds)

    // elapsed milliseconds since the last mousemove event
    var elapsedTime = Date.now() - moveTime;

    // max milliseconds allowed to elapse after a mousemove
    var thresholdTime = checkIfStoppedThreshold + allowedPrecisionError;

    // if the current time is "almost identical" to the time when we 
    // started our timer, that means the mouse has stopped moving and 
    // we can show the tooltip 
    if (elapsedTime <= thresholdTime) {

      isShown = true;

      tooltip.fadeIn(animationTime, function() {

        // reset the isShown flag once the animation finishes
        isShown = false; 
      });
    }
  }, checkIfStoppedThreshold);
};
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" />
<a href="#" id="target" title="Tooltip">Hover over me!</a>
```

Comment: this sound like a good idea! i'll try and let you know, thanks!

Comment: @arod, no problem, I added another possible solution, hope one of them helps :)

Comment: @arod, I removed the first solution and altered the second because they both had a flickering bug when the animation wasn't finished. Now the code is slightly more organized and customizable, with the flickering bug fixed.

Comment: your solution had some problems, like the tooltip was shown on first hover over target, and some flickering. yet it definitely pointed me in the right direction. and I thank you very much for it. please see my solution.